# Elastic search fetch +1 and -1 docuemnt for an id with sort and filter query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a query, this query returns a document and I have to retrieve the doc+1 and doc-1. Any suggestions. I cannot afford to do split this query?

**EDIT:**

The query:

```
 {
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "match" : {
        "company_id" : {
        "query" : "5d10b28a05b69a01f9284913",
        "operator" : "OR",
        "prefix_length" : 0,
        "max_expansions" : 50,
        "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
        "lenient" : false,
        "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
        "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query" : true,
        "boost" : 1.0
      }
    }
  }
],
"must_not" : [
  {
    "terms" : {
      "status" : [
        "IN_ACTIVE"
      ],
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
],
"adjust_pure_negative" : true,
"boost" : 1.0    
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell how you sort your documents? Can you show your base query?

Comment: @Val Edited the question. Please check

Comment: My question is, how do you want your documents to be sorted. If you want the -1 and +1 documents, you have to have some kind of sorting in mind.

Comment: Yeah. Let's assume for now descending by field ```company_id```

Comment: And company is alphanumeric (hexadecimal hash?) from what I can gather, right?

Comment: Yes, @Val. You are right

Comment: any other numeric field you could sort on instead?

Comment: I have another string. But not any int values. @Val

Comment: The next one is easy but the previous one is a bit harder without numeric value

Comment: Can you share the solution ? Maybe I reindex the documents with a numeric value if possible

Comment: Need sample documents to analyze!